# ViewPager content not able to reset after page scrolled

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I having a view pager, which having a textview and initially set to View.INVISIBLE and when the page comes to focus it fades in.

But when i am scrolled to next page and taking previous view the Text View is in Visible state but supposed to be in INVISIBLE state.

I tried with setting the textview to invisble through storing the previous index. But its not resetting the textview.

```
index = indexCalculator(index);
    Log.d("HeadIndex",""+index);
    CustomViewPagerAdapter customViewPagerAdapter = (CustomViewPagerAdapter) viewPagerAdapter;
    ImageSliderFragment fragment = customViewPagerAdapter.getFragment(index);
    fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.head_data).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Canyone help me how to set the view to INVISIBLE.

UPDATE Code:

```
private class CustomViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private Map<Integer, ImageSliderFragment> mPageReferenceMap = new HashMap<>();

    public CustomViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ImageSliderFragment imageSliderFragment = new ImageSliderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_FOR_FRAGMENT_POSITION,position);
        imageSliderFragment.setArguments(args);
        mPageReferenceMap.put(Integer.valueOf(position),imageSliderFragment);
        return imageSliderFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return AppConstants.NUM_PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;//super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return  super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public ImageSliderFragment getFragment(int key) {
        return mPageReferenceMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

PageChangeListener code:

```
public class CircularViewPagerHandler implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private int         mCurrentPosition;
private int         mScrollState;

///For determining swipe direction
private static final float thresholdOffset = 0.5f;
private boolean scrollStarted, checkDirection;

private HeadDataListener headDataListener;

public CircularViewPagerHandler(final ViewPager viewPager,HeadDataListener listener) {
    mViewPager = viewPager;
    headDataListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
    mCurrentPosition = position;
    headDataListener.showHead(position);
    Log.d("OnPageSelected",""+position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
    handleScrollState(state);
    mScrollState = state;
    if (!scrollStarted && state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
        scrollStarted = true;
        checkDirection = true;
    } else {
        scrollStarted = false;
    }
}

private void handleScrollState(final int state) {
    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        setNextItemIfNeeded();
    }
}

private void setNextItemIfNeeded() {
    if (!isScrollStateSettling()) {
         handleSetNextItem();
    }
}

private boolean isScrollStateSettling() {
    return mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING;
}

private void handleSetNextItem() {
    final int lastPosition = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1;
    if(mCurrentPosition == 0) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(lastPosition, false);
    } else if(mCurrentPosition == lastPosition) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
    if (checkDirection) {
        if (thresholdOffset > positionOffset) {
            AppConstants.SWIPE_DIRECTION = 1;
        } else {
            AppConstants.SWIPE_DIRECTION = 2;
        }
        checkDirection = false;
    }
}
```

}

I have implemented a callback to my class

Comment: Share more code. What do u do inside your CustomViewPagerAdapteer?

Comment: @EE66 have added the Adapter code...

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility of the view at the XML

> android:visibility="gone"

then change the visibity of the view at *onPageSelected()* method at the *CustomPagerAdapter*

Comment: I am doing the same, set a call back in onPageSelected and able to show the textview. But when view is swiped to next and scrolling back again the view is still visible. For that i have used the 1st set of code posted above to set the view again to invisible but thats not working.

Comment: I dont see onPageSelected(). At onPageSelected() you can hide the other textviews. The ones on the other fragments/views.

Comment: it was the fadein animation which makes problem. I was not cancelling the animation while the page is scrolled. Thanks anyway for your views and help :)